# MySQL - Left outer join not returning value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

I am trying to match the value of `Hold_Target` based on skill code but it's always returning as `NULL` no matter what I do. Am I doing something wrong in my query? Here's what I am using.

```
Select
    ei.TM,
    ei.emp_id,
    ei.DNAME,
    ei.STATUS,
    ei.SHIFT,
    ei.SKILL,
    ct.Target as Hold_Target
From
    mtl_extended_info ei
    Left outer join (
        Select
            ct.Skill,
            ct.Target as Target
        From
            cdl_threshold ct
        Where
            ct.Metric LIKE CONVERT(_utf8 '%Avg Hold Time%' USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
    ) ct on ct.SKILL = ei.SKILL
Where
    ei.Visible = 1
Group by
    ei.emp_id
Order By
    ei.SM,
    ei.TM,
    ei.DNAME
```

cdl_threshold table

```
 Skill   Metric            Target
 WR      Avg Hold Time     100
 CA      Avg Hold Time     100
```

Expected result

```
TM                  emp_id    DNAME       STATUS    SHIFT   SKILL   Hold_Target
Peter Parker        842448    Joe Doe     A         FT      CA      100
```

Comment: Showing the contents of the cdl_threshold table doesn't prove enough. Does your subquery return those results?

Comment: Can you provide the sample data? You can try to use `LIMIT` though.

Comment: Because of less data my answer is: Problem is here `ct.Metric LIKE CONVERT(_utf8 '%Avg Hold Time%' USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci`.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, it's returning the results that's why I don't understand.

Comment: @Christian Mark What do you mean sample data? What I am showing is a sample of the data tables

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I need that to define the metric.

Comment: can you check ei.Visible for selected record(842448) and why you need group by clause?

Comment: @shola This is only part of the query. I have other `JOIN` that use emp_id and ei.Visible to show if the person in the list is active or not.